# Stored Procedure Syintax

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to do write a stored procedure using MysQL, that let me insert, update or delete using parameters, into persona's table, who has the fields id_persona, nombres, apellidos & edad; so can you give me an idea why this is wrong about my stored procedure?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS guardarPersona$$
CREATE PROCEDURE persona(input_id_persona INT, input_nombres VARCHAR(100), input_apellidos VARCHAR(100), input_edad INT, input_accion VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
IF (input_accion='guardar') THEN
    INSERT INTO `persona`(`nombres`, `apellidos`, `edad`) VALUES (input_nombres,input_apellidos,input_edad);
ELSEIF (input_accion='modificar') THEN
    UPDATE `persona` SET `nombres`=input_nombres,`apellidos`=input_apellidos,`edad`=input_edad WHERE id_persona = input_id_persona;
ELSEIF (input_accion='eliminar') THEN
    DELETE FROM `persona` WHERE id_persona = input_id_persona;
ELSE
    mysql_error();
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is the mysql error....

> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '();
>
> END IF;
>   END' at line 10

Comment: only some sins get taxed, most of the real fun sins aren't taxed so far :)

Comment: i don't understand? what do you mean?

Comment: I think the error is with  mysql_error(); ..Try some other alternative

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_error()` function is using in API.

For get data of error inside stored procedure you should use `SHOW ERRORS;`

```
...
ELSE
    SHOW ERRORS;
END IF;
....
```